# Convert two-digit hex code to Unicode equivalent

Tags: java, android, unicode, hex, extended-ascii

I have a print format page that uses hex values to represent extended ASCII characters (resembling characters from IBM [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)). I am using this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference. I have no say over the format page so this cannot be changed.

This print format page is used in my Android application to place relevant data in the right place when sent to the printer. The final result should look something like an invoice.

I am having trouble with the representation of certain ASCII characters in Java. For example, from the table above, characters 201, 205, and 187. When combined in that order they from a nice border for my data table.

In Java I am trying to convert from hex to ASCII like this:

```
String hex = "D5"; //this is just for example
int n = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16); //this should return a value of 213
char c = (char)n;
```

"c" ends up being some wacky looking character that is not what I intended. I realize now it's because Java is using [Windows-1252/CP-1252 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

I think the solution would be to convert from the two-digit hex value to the corresponding Unicode value, but cannot figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: D5 hex = 213, not 201

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to go the extra mile?

```
private static final char TOP_LEFT = '╔';
private static final char HORIZONTAL = '═';
private static final char TOP_RIGHT = '╗';
```

And just use these... But beware, different fonts may represent these differently...

Comment: The assumption is that different formats will use different hex values to represent their extended ASCII counterparts. This seems like a hard-coded solution to me.

How did you represent those ASCII characters as strings?

Comment: @F.Ali If it would use **different character code**, then no matter what you do, it won't represent the char you want.  "D5" would be just as hard coded as my solution... By the way, you can get ASCII characters on Windows by Alt + <ASCII number in radix 10>, so hold `Alt` key while enter `201` on the numpad.  I'm not sure about other OSes, I never tried this bit anywhere else...

Comment: D5 is just an example... The hex value that the program receives can be anything.

Comment: @F.Ali You can store the exact `char`s external to zour program too: XML, .property file, DB, whatever... I still don't get what the problem is with directly having the characters, instead of a representation of them

Comment: I have reworded the question as I learn more about my problem. I appreciate your help and hope this clears up any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the String constructor [that takes byte[] and Charset arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), using a Charset that's appropriate for the data you're receiving ("IBM437").